# Sort order with masonry like css disturbed

Tags: html, css, layout

I have rendered items with masonry like layout with css. But, the sort order of the items is disturbed. below is the image which has numbers with each item. They should be sorted according to the numbers in rows not columns. I have tried flex also which distorted the layout. So, i want to do it with out flex. Here is the css code:

```
ul.ads-collection {
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 0.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0.5em;
    column-gap: 0.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
}

ul.ads-collection li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0.2em;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<ul class="ads-collection">
    <li>
        <div class="ad">
            <img src=".." alt="No Image" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="col-xs-12 padding-bottom-10 padding-top-10">
                <h2 class="no-margins"><a href="javascript:;" class="no-margins"><strong>1 - Testing classified</strong></a></h2>
                <span class="location font-weight-normal">Abu Dhabi</span>
                <span class="price font-red font-weight-normal"><strong>536</strong> AED</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="ad">
            <div class="col-xs-12 padding-bottom-10 padding-top-10">
                <h2 class="no-margins"><a href="javascript:;" class="no-margins"><strong>2 - Samsung Galaxy Golden i9235</strong></a></h2>
                <span class="location font-weight-normal">Dubai</span>
                <span class="price font-red font-weight-normal"><strong>500</strong> AED</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: try to post HTML code or jsfiddle link. I think instead of column property use  display: inline-block and assign width to each li in % or use float

Comment: *" They should be sorted according to the numbers in rows not columns."* This is NOT possible with CSS Flexbox. You need javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get a sort by line with the css column-count function. A solution will be possible when the CSS3 Grid Layout will be correctly supported by the browsers, but we have only the use of javascript at the moment.

```
// With Stylus preprocessor:

$gutter = 1.5rem
$sizeXS = 36.01rem

.masonry
  margin $gutter 0
  column-gap $gutter

@media (min-width $sizeXS)
  .masonry
    column-count 2

// etc...
```

[Responsive Masonry in CSS only](https://codepen.io/olivier-c/pen/KNvVMq)